# Downcasting a const std::list<const unique_ptr<Base>>

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a modular software, and I'm heading some problem with interfaces and memory.

I've a `Base` class with some heavy work with association and composition so I prefer to write it once in an interface. Problem is to avoid any memory leak or problems only my base class should be able to see the fields. Nobody else than `Base` should modify `mFields` list or free the pointers it contains.

The problem is `BaseField` will be derived, and methods will be added and my program who will use the `Derived` method should directly get list of `DerivedField`:

```
class BaseField {} ;
class DerivedField : public BaseField {} ;

class Base {
protected:
    unique_ptr<BaseField> & addField(unique_ptr<BaseField> f) ;
    const unique_ptr<BaseField> & something() ;
    const unique_ptr<BaseField> & something2() ;
    const std::list<const unique_ptr<BaseField>> & getFields() ;
private:
    std::list<const unique_ptr<BaseField>> mFields ;
}

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    unique_ptr<DerivedField> & addField(params) ;
    const unique_ptr<DerivedField> & something() ;
    const unique_ptr<DerivedField> & something2() ;
    const std::list<const unique_ptr<DerivedField>> & getFields() ;
}
```

So my question is how to get 
`const std::list<const unique_ptr<DerivedField>> &` in `Derived::getFields()` with `Base::getFields()` ?

EDIT:

I think I didn't explain my problem clearly. I understand what @NicolBolas is saying and I agreee with him but doesn't really help me so let's present it that way:

My software should solve different problems types such as `Problem1` `Problem2` and `Problem3`

The fact is all of thoses problem have exactly same subproblems structure such as `SubProblem1` `SubProblem2` `SubProblem3`
So to avoid code repetition I decide to write a `BaseProblem` class and a `BaseSubProblems` who will repesent the structure and the comon operations for every Problem (such as `addSubProblem(BaseSubProblem *)`).
Base problem is not instanciable because protected constructor (it's only a structure provided to avoid code repetition). Also the `addSubProblem(SubProblem *)` method is protected so only `derived` `Problem` can add `SubProblem`
Because of that every user who creates a `Problem1` know that all of the SubProblem contained in `Problem1` are type of `SubProblem1`.

So actually I use `std::list<SubProblem *>` in `BaseProblem` and my `derived Problem class` gives access with `std::list<SubProblem1 *> Problems1::getSubProblems()`
I would like to be able to declare that only `BaseProblem` owns the `SubProbblems` even if only the `derived Problems` know the real type of `SubProblems`

I hope this explanation is better than the previous one.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but you should use `std::list<std::unique_ptr<const BaseField>>` instead of `std::list<const unique_ptr<BaseField>>`. I also want to know why you are returning `const unique_ptr<T>&` instead of `T*`.

Comment: The fact is I really don't want that anybody can take the ownership of my `DerivedField`. I'm 100% sure that all of the `BaseField` are `DerivedField`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. In fact, you can't implement *any* of your `Derived` interface like that. C++ doesn't work that way.

The types `unique_ptr<Derived>` and `unique_ptr<Base>` are completely unrelated types, as far as C++ is concerend. You cannot cast or convert a value, pointer, or reference of one type to the other. Well, you can with pointers/references, but you will get undefined behavior. The same goes for `std::list<T>`.

Your problem is that you seem to want to pass references to a `unique_ptr` around. This is a poor API. If someone takes a `unique_ptr`, then that should mean that they are `claiming ownership` of that object. By passing a `unique_ptr` to `addField`, the caller is telling `Base` to take ownership of that pointer. For it to return a reference to that pointer is a violation of the unique ownership idea of a `unique_ptr`.

`addField` and its ilk should just return naked pointers: `Base*` and such. With naked pointers, there are no ownership implications.

As for `getFields`... well, you're going to have to come up with an API based on naked pointers for exposing such a list. Maybe you should internally have a `vector<Base*>` that you can expose, or you could create an iterator wrapper around `list`'s iterators that extract the pointer from the `unique_ptr`.

It should also be noted that this faux-overriding syntax you're using, where the derived class hides base class member functions with versions that use its own pointers, is generally poor OOP style. It requires way too much "downcasting", which is dangerous and il-advised. There's nothing stopping a user from sending something that isn't a `Derived` into `addFields` in the base class, and users of the class should not themselves care one way or the other.

And if they have to care, then you're doing OOP wrong.

Comment: I forgot top write the relation between Base and Derived. Actually I'm doing it with naked pointer, but I try to improve my C++ level by reading Bjarne Stroustrup book. So I decided to clearly tells that only my Base class owns the fields but users who will use the Derived class shoudln't care about Base class.

Comment: @QuentinHuot-Marchand: Your clarification doesn't change anything. You still shouldn't be returning references to `unique_ptr`s or to containers containing them. And if users of `Derived` shouldn't care about `Base`, then you're still using OOP wrong.